# Conservation of Linear Momentum in presence of hinge forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I was recently instructed by my instructor that say if a person is standing on a disc(stationary and hinged) and decides to jump off it then linear momentum of system is not conserved as **a hinge force acts on the body thus preventing conservation of momentum** Can somebody please explain how the hinge force acts in this case and explain the situation to me? 
Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For linear momentum-

initial linear momentum is $0$, but when the person jumps with velocity 'v' with respect to disc, to conserve linear momentum of system , disc would try to gain linear momentum in opposite direction to the person, which would have same magnitude of that of person's but just opposite in direction for cancelling each other .

But again there is a hinge which prevents disc from moving, which would otherwise had cancelled the linear momentum gained by person and the final linear momentum would again had been converted to $0$ as it was in the initial condition, but it is not so,so surely there is a force about the hinge, as the linear momentum is not conserved

Comment: Your Answer about angular momentum is wrong as The net torque on the system is zero (about center of disc) thus change in angular momentum is zero.

Answer (score 1):

A hinge is nothing but a mechanical setup which allows restricted rotation. Whenever we have a hinge and a body is rotating we have reaction forces generated by the hinge. When the person jumps from the disc he applies a force F backwards on the disc tangentially and the disc applies a force F forward on the person these are action and reaction forces. But because of person pushing the disc , the hinge about which disc is rotating that generates a reaction force to prevent the disc from gaining a linear velocity ie Centre of mass of the disc is not gaining any velocity linearly as it is hinged and it is preventing it from gaining velocity. So there is a net external force due to this hinge , although the forces of man and disc cancel out due to action and reaction but still hinge forces are there so we cannot conserve linear momentum.

But angular momentum is conserved as net torque about centre of disc is zero as hinge forces are passing through centre and torque of action and reaction forces cancel out with each other.